# When using \caption\expandafter\var{test} a new line is introduced?

Tags: captions, variable

I'm using `\var{}` in a caption but it introduces a new line?

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, trim=1.2cm 6.7cm 1.2cm 0.8cm,clip]{P40_con_red_12.pdf}
        \caption\expandafter{\var{test}}
\end{table}
```

Output:
Table 1.1:
test

I want:
Table 1.1: test

Comment: You aren’t saying what `\var` is supposed to do, but `\expandafter` is out of place there. Remove it

Comment: Hi egreg, thank for the swift  answer. So the \var is a variable (taken form another file) which I would like to use in the caption. If I only use \caption{\var{test}} i get an error: ! Undefined control sequence.
\edtlgetrowforvalue ...def \@dtl@dogetrowforvalue 
{\noexpand \dtlgetrowforva...
l.132         \caption{\var{test}}

Comment: if you want help with an error provide a test file that makes the error and show exactly the error message that you get, copied from the log file to a code block in the question. Not in comments as you need the line endings to understand the error message.

Comment: the `@dtl` prefix suggests you are using the dataool package but I see no `\var` command defined there?

Answer (score 1):

`\caption\expandafter` is `\caption{\expandafter}` so the caption is just `\expandafter` which will give you a blank caption (which you are seeing as a newline) then the intended caption text is typeset as a paragraph after the caption.

The intended markup is presumably

```
 \caption{\var{test}}
```

but you have not said how `\var` is defined.

You would get the desired output if you removed `\var` as well and simply had

```
\caption{test}
```

You have not given any indication of how `\var` is defined but if it is a fragile command than you will need to protect it with

```
\caption{\protect\var{test}}
```

Comment: The \var{test} is imported from a dat-file using key, value. When \var{test} is used in the document it works perfectly by when I want to use it in a caption like this  \caption{\var{test}} it gives me the following error 
132
Undefined control sequence.
\edtlgetrowforvalue ...def \@dtl@dogetrowforvalue 
                                                  {\noexpand \dtlgetrowforva...
l.132         \caption{\var{test}}
(I new to latex - thanks for helping)

Comment: as I said under the question it's impossible to read error messages if you post in comments as the line endings are required to understand the structure of the message. Also if you provide no example how `\var` is defined it will be very hard to offer more help. " imported from a dat-file using key, value." means nothing in a general latex context, you must be using some definition that allows you to define `\var` @JensHøgh

Comment: @JensHøgh unless you want to try a random guess and try `\caption{\protect\var{test}}`

Comment: Perfect \caption{\protect\var{test}}  worked :)  I had googled at least 2 hours .....thanks!